# How to update json object value in state using checkbox in react form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have the following state in Form.jsx

```
this.state = {
      name: "",
      contact: "",
      company: "",
      mail: "",
      key: {
        val1: false,
        val2: false,
        val3: false
      },
```

I am trying to update the value in KEY i;e val1, val2 using  checkboxes. I want to set it equal to true when checkbox is clicked. I am a bit confused on how to set a particular value.
I am using setState to update the value but it still remains false.
My code looks something like this.

```
handleKey(e) {
    let change = {};
    change[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    console.log("value: " + e.target.value);
    let key = this.state.key;
    this.setState({
      wedding: e.target.value,
      MICE: e.target.value,
      corporate: e.target.value
    });
  }
```

And this is my forms:

```
<Form.Group controlId="formBasicChecbox">
            <Form.Label> Key </Form.Label>
            <Form.Check
              value={this.state.key.weeding}
              onChange={e => this.handleKey(e)}
              name="key"
              type="checkbox"
              label="Wedding"
            />
            <Form.Check
              value={this.state.key.MICE}
              onChange={e => this.handleKey(e)}
              name="key"
              type="checkbox"
              label="MICE"
            />
            <Form.Check
              value={this.state.key.corporate}
              onChange={e => this.handleKey(e)}
              name="key"
              type="checkbox"
              label="Corporate"
            />
          </Form.Group>
```

Comment: I recommend setting up a state debugger so that you can see the application (& checkbox) state as you try to change it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to do something like:

```
handleKey (e) {
  const {value, checked, name} = e.target;
  const previousKeyState = this.state[name] || {}; 
  this.setState({
    [name]: {...previousKeyState, [name]: checked}
  });
}
```

See demo below.

```js
const fields = {
  wookies: ['chewie', 'chewbacca'],
  hats: ['fedora', 'cowboy', 'top']
};

class FormDemo extends React.Component {
  state = {}
  
  handleCheckbox = (e) => {
const {name, value, checked} = e.target;
const previousState = this.state[name] || {};
this.setState({
  [name]: {...previousState, [value]: checked}
});
  }

  render () {
return (
  <div>
    {Object.entries(fields).map(([name, options]) => {
      return (
        <fieldgroup key={name}>
          <div>{name}</div>
          {options.map(o => (
            <label key={o}>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                onClick={this.handleCheckbox}
                name={name}
                value={o}
                checked={(this.state[name] || {})[o]}
              />
              {o}
            </label>
          ))}
        </fieldgroup>
      );        
    })
  }
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
  </div>
);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<FormDemo />, document.getElementById('demo'));
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

fieldgroup {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the state to the currently rendered value.  Since the current value is whatever is initially rendered, you are always setting it to the same false/unchecked state.

So you want to "toggle" the checkbox boolean state yourself when the change event happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should be done like this in handle change and keep in mind change text name as well:

```
this.setState({
      ...this.state,key:{...this.state.key,[e.target.name]:e.target.value}
    });
  }
```

and change your checkbox name otherwise it will update same value for ex:

```
<Form.Check
              value={this.state.key.corporate}
              onChange={e => this.handleKey(e)}
              name="key"
              type="checkbox"
              label="Corporate"
            />
```

should be

```
<Form.Check
              value={this.state.key.corporate}
              onChange={e => this.handleKey(e)}
              name="Corporate" // name of checkbox you want to change(act as unique identifier)
              type="checkbox"
              label="Corporate"
            />
```